# Handlebars - How to navigate JSON data for template

Tags: arrays, json, handlebars.js

I have JSON data that look like:

{
    "review": {
        "count": "1",
        "summary": [
            {
                "Q1": "9.50",
                "Q2": "9.50",
                "Q3": "9.00",
                "Q4": "8.75",
                "Q5": "7.63",
                "Q6": "8.88",
                "Q7": "9.38",
                "Q8": "9.75",
                "Q9": "9.38",
                "Q10": "9.00",
                "Q11": "9.75",
                "Q12": "9.75",
                "Q13": "9.75",
                "Q14": "8.13",
                "Q15": "9.00",
                "Q16": "8.88",
                "Q17": "8.00",
                "Q18": "9.38",
                "Q19": "9.88",
                "Q20": "10.00",
                "Q21": "10.00",
                "Q22": "7.00",
                "Q23": "9.75",
                "Q24": "9.25",
                "Q25": "8.63",
                "Q26": "9.00",
                "Q27": "6.50",
                "Q28": "9.50",
                "Q29": "9.63",
                "Q30": "9.75",
                "Q31": "9.38",
                "Q32": "8.63",
                "Q33": "9.50",
                "Q34": "7.38",
                "Q35": "6.88",
                "Q36": "7.38",
                "Q37": "9.88",
                "Q38": "9.50",
                "Q39": "7.75",
                "Q40": "8.25",
                "Q41": "9.75",
                "Q42": "9.75",
                "Q43": "9.63",
                "Q44": "9.38",
                "Q45": "9.88",
                "Q46": "9.38",
                "Q47": "10.00",
                "Q48": "9.88",
                "Q49": "10.00",
                "Q50": "9.88",
                "Q51": "9.75",
                "Q52": "9.38"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I am trying to create a Handlebars template that allows me to iterate a certain div block.  I am trying to list the @index values for the "summary" section, but can't seem to find the correct syntax to get at them.

I can get

```
{{#each reviews.summary}}

{{/each }}
```

I have tried to use {{#key}} within that each statment, but I get 0 - which is the array key for the first item in "summary".  How could I output the list of key values within that array?  Essentially, Q1, Q2,...etc.

Comment: i was just playing around with this and realized the data is really awkward (i see the problem now). summary is an array but with only one (giant) object! {{each}} seems reasonable but there is only 1 thing to loop; you need the 52 properties. the template is in a script so i'm thinking that a loop through the props might work?

Comment: did you see the answer below?

Comment: Hi wazz, yes I did see the answer - I just have not had a chance to try to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

this works for the first property:

```
{{#each review.summary}}
    {{Q1}}
{{/each }}
```

---

edit:

handlebars template:

```
{{#each qdata}}
    {{this}}
{{/each }}
```

js:

```
// new function:
function getQData(data) {
    var arQData = [];
    var obj = data.review.summary[0]; // here's the data we need.

    for (var prop in obj) {
        //alert("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
        arQData.push(obj[prop]);
    }
    return arQData;
}

// create a new object for the filtered data. this seemed
// necessary (?) so i could put 'qdata' in the html template.
// call (new) function that does the filtering. 
// dataIn argument is the JSON data.
var d = { qdata: getQData(dataIn) };

// handlebars stuff.
var context = d;
var html = template(context);
$("#results").html(html); // wherever your results go.
```

object properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: i used the simple version of getting object properties. you  might want to use the `hasOwnProperty()` version.