# How to display Json Data getting [object object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.questions, function (index, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}); // getJSON
```

Data JSON:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "qset": {
                "q1": "Template 1 question1",
                "q2": "Template 1 question2",
                "q3": "Template 1 question3",
                "q4": "Template 1 question4",
                "q5": "Template 1 question5"
            }
        },
        {
            "qset": {
                "q1": "Template 2 question1",
                "q2": "Template 2 question2",
                "q3": "Template 2 question3",
                "q4": "Template 2 question4",
                "q5": "Template 2 question5"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to display data via JSON using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327231/best-way-to-display-data-via-json-using-jquery)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086322/handlebars-how-to-navigate-json-data-for-template/33094038#33094038

Comment: also, that is not valid json. (http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 1):

JUST validate your json,then try to console your `json properties`

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "qset": {
                "q1": "Template 1 question1",
                "q2": "Template 1 question2",
                "q3": "Template 1 question3",
                "q4": "Template 1 question4",
                "q5": "Template 1 question5"
            }
        },
        {
            "qset": {
                "q1": "Template 2 question1",
                "q2": "Template 2 question2",
                "q3": "Template 2 question3",
                "q4": "Template 2 question4",
                "q5": "Template 2 question5"
            }
        } //remove comma
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a nested `each` loop to get at the inner objects:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.questions, function (index, question) {
       $.each(question.qset, function (index1, qset) {
        console.log(qset);
      });
   });
});
```